# Automator flow halting and failing to pass input to next step

Tags: macos, automator

I have an Automator script that looks like this, to filter files added to my Downloads folder into subfolders:

[image]

The problem is that, if there are no files in the folder with any of those extensions, it halts execution of the script:

[image]

Is there any way to have the `Move Finder Items` portion of the script skip if it doesn't receive any inputs?

Comment: I am pretty certain that Automator does not have the capability to test like that.  You will either need to use a **Run AppleScript** Action, or do the whole thing as an AppleScript.